# SQL: How to split a column of type varchar?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table that has a column named 'languages', but it has the following types of values :

```
english; polish; portuguese;
```

.. etc.

I want to split so I can insert it in another table as:

```
english
polish
portugese
```

And go on.

I already searched in Google and find this split function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split (@sep char(1), @s varchar(512))
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
    WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
      SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + 1)
      FROM Pieces
      WHERE stop > 0
    )
    SELECT pn,
      SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END) AS s
    FROM Pieces
  )
```

I already tested it with this :

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Split(' ', 'I hate bunnies')
```

So I tried to adapt this to my case :

```
INSERT INTO labbd11..language(language) SELECT s FROM dbo.Split(';', disciplinabd..movies.languages)
```

Then it gives me this exception:

```
The multi-part identifier "disciplinabd..movies.languages" could not be bound. Severity 16
```

Any ideas ?

Best regards,
Valter Henrique.

Comment: A design that combines values into a single entry that you have to parse breaks first normal form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CROSS APPLY

```
INSERT INTO labbd11..language(language)
SELECT DISTINCT s.s
FROM disciplinabd..movies m
CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(';', m.languages)  S
```

But if I read your query correctly, you are splitting the languages from **ALL** movies, and inserting the resultant languages from the movie into the language table (1 column only).  Hope this is a test query, otherwise it has no business merit at all.

Comment: you read right, i want to normalize my database so i will split this language column to another table where is gonna be : id, language only, so every language has an id.

And keeps give the same error before:
The multi-part identifier "m.languages" could not be bound. Severity 16

Comment: Did you alias the movies table as m? Sorry, I changed from CROSS JOIN to CROSS APPLY. Thought one thing, typed another.

Comment: @Valter / you should be able to just add `WHERE s.s is not null`